# DISTINCT values from a RIGHT JOIN in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three relational tables, structure with samples as follows.

```
properties:

property_id | property_name | county_id 
------------|---------------|-------
     1      | Davis Court   |   2
     2      | Rose Lodge    |   1
     3      | Haven Court   |   4
     4      | Great Lodge   |   1
     5      | Lilly Court   |   2
     6      | Miles Lodge   |   4
     7      | Priory Court  |   5


testimonials:

testimonlal_id | property_id | message
---------------|-------------|------------------
      1        |    4        |   blah blah blah
      2        |    2        |   blah blah blah
      3        |    6        |   blah blah blah
      4        |    3        |   blah blah blah
      5        |    1        |   blah blah blah
      6        |    7        |   blah blah blah
      7        |    5        |   blah blah blah

counties:

county_id | county_name
----------|----------------
    1     | Berkshire
    2     | Devon
    3     | Essex
    4     | Kent
    5     | Surrey
```

I want to display distinct county names for all testimonials in the table. I currently have the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT properties.county_id, counties.county_id, 
counties.county_name, testimonials.testimonial_id 
FROM properties 
LEFT JOIN counties 
  ON properties.county_id = counties.county_id 
RIGHT JOIN testimonials 
  ON properties.property_id = testimonials.property_id 
ORDER BY properties.county_id ASC
```

this currently gives me

```
Berkshire
Berkshire
Devon
Devon
Kent
Kent
Surrey
```

But I want

```
Berkshire
Devon
Kent
Surrey
```

This could possibly need the use of the UNION or GROUP BY operators but I am unsure how to adapt the query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are selecting 4 columns and want only one? Remove the unwanted columns

Comment: there are multiple `testimonial_id`, ofcourse you will get the duplicate county names

Comment: I don't understand those outer joins. (Well, right outer joins are hard enough to read, and mixed with left outer joins that's quite horrible.) What are you trying to achieve? Can there be testimonials without a property? Can there be properties without a county? Are you maybe looking for counties, too, that have no property? And/or properties that have no testimonials?

Comment: And please clarify: You are showing an impossible result for the query. The query selects four columns, the result contains one. Which of the two do you actually want? Maybe you can put in words what the result is supposed to contain/represent?

Comment: What I have so far might be completely wrong in the approach alas why i am posting this. what I am trying to achieve here is to display testimonials  and filter them by county from a dropdown list. So I have tried to build the county list but need to do this including the testimonial_id so I can display all counties used in all testimonials. To answer your questions.. Each testimonial will have property and each property will have a county. But not all properties have testimonials. In my actual tables there are 42 testimonials, 134 properties and 30 counties

Comment: You want that dropdown list not to contain 'Essex', because there are no testimonials for that county? And you want to select all testimonials and then filter them in your app with that dropdown without having to access the database again?

Comment: In my sample the dropdown list will not contain Essex which is being achieved. But It is displaying a county name for each testimonial. Consequently I am getting repeat counties in the list. But I only want each county in the list to be displayed once. Apologies but I probably should have stated, as obvious as it may be, that I am using PHP to display the database values on the web page. So the purpose for this is when a county is selected, all Testimonials from that county are displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unclear why you select `testimonials.testimonial_id` when it's counties you want to select for your dropdown box. Simply removing it from the select list would result in the counties without duplicates.

You can get this even clearer by not joining (and thus not having to dismiss rows with `DISTINCT`). When it's counties you want to select, then select from `counties`. If you have criteria which counties to select, then put this criteria in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select county_name, county_id
from counties
where county_id in
(
  select county_id
  from properties
  where property_id in (select property_id from testimonials)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this @ThorstonKettner, without really understanding the syntax i've got this working. i've never used the IN operator so need to get up to speed with this. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it's a good idea to read up on `IN`. It is very easy to understand. You should do the same for `EXISTS` which we use for more complicated lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* testimonials, then start with that table and use `left join`:

```
SELECT c.county_id, c.county_name, t.testimonial_id 
FROM testimonials t LEFT JOIN
     properties p
     ON p.property_id = t.property_id LEFT JOIN
     counties c
     ON p.county_id = c.county_id 
ORDER BY p.county_id ASC;
```

Notes:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` should be unnecessary, unless you have duplicates in the underlying tables.  If so, put it back in.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- When using outer joins I recommend sticking only to `LEFT JOIN`s.  The logic is easier to follow:  "Keep all tables in the first table, with matching columns from the remaining tables.
- There is no need to select `county_id` twice.

Comment: thanks for this @GordonLinoff but this still gives me repeated counties in the dropdown list. As it displays every 'county' for every 'testimonial', with or without DISTINCT.

Comment: Use `distinct` and remove the testimonial id.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4bcc2/11

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
p.county_id p_county_id, c.county_id c_county_id, c.county_name, t.testimonial_id, t.message
FROM properties p
LEFT JOIN counties c
  ON p.county_id = c.county_id 
RIGHT JOIN testimonials t
  ON p.property_id = t.property_id 
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  p.county_id ORDER BY [testimonial_id]);
```

Comment: Nice query to get the first testimonial per county, but on one hand I don't think this is being asked and on the other the question is on MySQL, not SQL Server.